# How to find the sum .. a question in differential calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got this question in one of my book under " Differential Calculus"

Compute the sum :

$2+2.3x+3.4x^2+.....+n(n-1)x^{n-2}$

Getting no clue of how to approach this problems.. please guide... Thanks..

Comment: What happens if you differentiate $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ twice?

Comment: Start with the geometric series and differentiate a couple of times.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** it looks like a second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
$$1+x+x^2+...+x^n = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$ Differentiate twice.

Next time please do post your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with just algebra,
though the differentiating method is much easier.

Let $S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n P(k)x^k$,
where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.
In your case, $d=2$ and $P(k) = (k+1)(k+2)$.

$\begin{align}
x S(n) &= x\sum_{k=0}^n P(k)x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n P(k)x^{k+1}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P(k-1)x^{k}\\
\end{align}
$

so

$\begin{align}
 S(n) - xS(n) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n P(k)x^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P(k-1)x^{k}\\
&= P(0) - P(n)x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n (P(k)-P(k-1))x^k\\
\end{align}$.

Since $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d$,
$P(k)-P(k-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $d-1$,
because the high degree term gets removed.
In your case,

$\begin{align}
P(k-1)-P(k) &= (k+1)(k+2)-k(k+1)\\
&= (k^2+3k+2)-(k^2+k) \\
&= 2k+2\\
\end{align}
$.

Let $Q(k) = P(k)-P(k-1)$,
where $Q$ has degree $d-1$,
and let
$T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n Q(k)x^k$.
Since $Q(0) = P(0)-P(-1)$,
$T(n) =Q(0)+ \sum_{k=1}^n Q(k)x^k
=P(0)-P(-1)+ \sum_{k=1}^n Q(k)x^k
$,
so 
$\sum_{k=1}^n Q(k)x^k
=T(n)-P(0)+P(-1)
$.

Then

$\begin{align}
 S(n)(1 - x)&=S(n) - xS(n)\\
&= P(0) - P(n)x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n Q(k)x^k\\
&=P(0) - P(n)x^{n+1}+T(n)-P(0)+P(-1)\\
&=P(-1)- P(n)x^{n+1}+T(n)\\
\end{align}
$

so
$$S(n) = \frac{P(-1)- P(n)x^{k+1}+T(n)}{1-x}$$
(unless I have make an error somewhere along the line).

We have reduced the problem of finding
$S(n)$ to finding $T(n)$,
where the polynomial in $T(n)$ has a smaller degree than
the one in $S(n)$.

In your case,
$T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (2k+2)x^k$,
$P(-1) = 0$,
and $P(n) = (n+1)(n+2)$,
so
$S(n) = \frac{- (n+1)(n+2)x^{k+1}+T(n)}{1-x}$
(again, modulo possible errors,
since I am doing this off the top of my head).

Applying this to $T(n)$,
since $Q(k) = 2k+2$,
$Q(k)-Q(k-1) = 2k+2 - (2(k-1)+2)
=2$,
so the sum we get is
$\sum_{k=0}^n 2x^k
= 2\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

The general principle is that
if the inside polynomial $P$ is of degree $d$,
the resulting function for $S(n)$
is a polynomial of degree $n+d+1$
divided by $(1-x)^{d+1}$.
This is because at each step
we increase the degree of the high order term
in the numerator by 1
and divide by $1-x$.
Doing this $d$ times,
the polynomial inside the sum
is reduced to a constant,
and the denominator becomes $(1-x)^d$.
The final step, when the sum is
$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$
gives the final $1/(1-x)$.

As something of a check,
if $d=0$, the polynomial is constant
so we get the constant times
$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.